# Is there any way to handle such kind of loop (for loop)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a agar.io clone and I am not understanding how I can handle my split mechanism. For splitting the blobs I have made a function which takes a blob as argument.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Play Agario Clone</title>

 <style>
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game">
  kindly update your browser.
 </canvas>

 <script>
 var 
 canvas, 
 ctx, 
 width = innerWidth, 
 height = innerHeight,
 mouseX = 0,
 mouseY = 0;

 var

 camera = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,

  // camera
  update: function(obj) {
   this.x = (obj.blobsExtent.minx + obj.blobsExtent.maxx) / 2;
      this.y = (obj.blobsExtent.miny + obj.blobsExtent.maxy) / 2;
      this.x -= width / 2;
      this.y -= height / 2;
  }
 },

 player = {
  defaultMass: 54,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  blobs: [],

  blobsExtent : {
      minx :0,
      miny : 0,
      maxx : 0,
      maxy : 0,
    },

  update: function () {
   var be = this.blobsExtent;
   for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i ++) {
    var x = mouseX + camera.x - this.blobs[i].x;
    var y = mouseY + camera.y - this.blobs[i].y;
    var length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
    var speed = 54/this.blobs[i].mass;
    
    this.blobs[i].velX = x/length * speed;
    this.blobs[i].velY = y/length * speed;

    this.blobs[i].x += this.blobs[i].velX;
    this.blobs[i].y += this.blobs[i].velY;

    //if (this.blobs[i].splitted) {
     //this.blobs[i].x += this.blobs[i].speed;
     //this.blobs[i].y += this.blobs[i].speed;

     //if (this.blobs[i].speed > 0) {
      //this.blobs[i].speed--;
     //}
    //}

    for (var j = 0; j < this.blobs.length; j ++) {
     if (j != i && this.blobs[i] !== undefined) {
            var blob1 = this.blobs[i];
            var blob2 = this.blobs[j];
            var x = blob2.x - blob1.x;
            var y = blob2.y - blob1.y;
            var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

            if (dist < blob1.mass + blob2.mass) {
              x /= dist;
              y /= dist;
              blob1.x = blob2.x - x * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
              blob1.y = blob2.y - y * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
            }
          }
    }

    if (i === 0) {
          be.maxx = be.minx = blob1.x;
          be.maxy = be.miny = blob1.y;
        } else {
          be.maxx = Math.max(be.maxx, blob1.x);
          be.maxy = Math.max(be.maxy, blob1.y);
          be.minx = Math.min(be.minx, blob1.x);
          be.miny = Math.min(be.miny, blob1.y);
        }
   }

   this.x += (mouseX - width/2)/(width/2) * 1;
   this.y += (mouseY - height/2)/(height/2) * 1
  },

  split: function (cell) {
   if(cell.mass >= this.defaultMass) {
    cell.mass /= 2;

    this.blobs.push({
     x: cell.x,
     y: cell.y,
     mass: cell.mass,
     splitted: true,
     speed: 20
    });
   }
  },

  draw: function () {
   for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i ++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(-camera.x + this.blobs[i].x, -camera.y + this.blobs[i].y, this.blobs[i].mass, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
   }
  }
 };

 function handleMouseMove (e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
 }

 function handleKeydown (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
   for (var i = 0; i < player.blobs.length; i++) {
    player.split(player.blobs[i]);
   }
  }
 }

 function setup () {
  canvas = document.getElementById("game");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
  addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);

  player.blobs.push({
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   mass: player.defaultMass
  });
  player.blobs.push({
   x: 100,
   y: 100,
   mass: player.defaultMass/2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
   x: 100,
   y: 100,
   mass: player.defaultMass*2
  });

  var loop = function () {
   update();
   draw();
   requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }

 function update () {
  camera.update(player);
  player.update();
 }

 function draw () {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  player.draw();
 }

 setup();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am calling the split function inside a for loop (because I need all the blobs to be splitted at once) when the spacebar (keycode == 32) is pressed. I want it to split only the blobs which are present at the time of split and not the blobs which comes after split. But it is splitting all of them.

Comment: Thank you for including such a complete example for your problem :) Could you also highlight the section of code you're particularly concerned with? That would really help people help with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the loop.

```
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        for (var i = 0; i < player.blobs.length; i++) {
            player.split(player.blobs[i]);
        }
    }
```

Every time you add a blob you increase the length of the array. As that length is used to end the for loop you keep looping over the ones you add.

To fix just get the length before you do the loop.

```
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        var currentLength = player.blobs.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < currentLength; i++) {
            player.split(player.blobs[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanx it worked. I didn't try it because i thought the variable will update its value when the loop checks the condition.